# How to clear the selected values from bootstrap tokenfield?

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

Is there a way to clear selected values from [bootstrap tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#methods) without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: I think there is only option to destroy it and to re-init it again. Don't see any clear option.

Comment: @vijayP: It's a shame they haven't thought about it. I ended up doing something similar. "destroy" does not clear the values in the textbox. So we have to set inputbox.val('') before re-initialising.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
$('#txt_contactos_aaduanal').tokenfield('setTokens', []);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear method.

In my case I had to retrieve a collection of email address from the server and assign them to a token field. I hope this will help someone.

```
        var emailData = []; //variable to hold data

        var getting = $.get("/MyController/GetEmailAddresses", function() {
        });
        getting.done(function(data) { 
            if (data != null) {
                $('#to-addresses').tokenfield('destroy');
                emailData = data; //assign data to global variable                 
                $('#to-addresses').tokenfield({ //initialise token field
                    autocomplete: {
                        source: data,
                        delay: 100,
                    },
                    showAutocompleteOnFocus: false
                });
            }
        });

        //Clear what's in the token field when uses presses the 'Clear' button
        $('#clear').on('click', function () {
        $('#to-addresses').tokenfield('destroy');
        $('#to-addresses').val('');//clear the text box
        $('#to-addresses').tokenfield({
            autocomplete: {
                source: emailData,//assign values from the global variable
                delay: 100,
            },
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: false
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

for remove all items after destroy redeclare

```
       $('#destroy').on('click', function() {
            $('.tokenfield').removeAttr('data-fouc').tokenfield('destroy');
            $('.tokenfield').tokenfield({
            autocomplete: {
                source: sourceDataObj,
                delay: 100
            },
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
            });
        });
```